# What does Uncle Bob mean by 'noun phrase names'?

Tags: coding-style, terminology, code-quality, naming

I am reading *Clean Code* by Uncle Bob. Because I am not a native-English speaker, I couldn't understand following statement:

> Classes and objects should have noun or noun phrase names like
>   `Customer`, `WikiPage`, `Account`, and `AddressParser`. Avoid words like
>   `Manager`, `Processor`, `Data`, or `Info` in the name of a class. A class name
>   should not be a verb.

As I know, none of the `Manager`, `Processor`, `Data`, and `Info` is a verb, isn't it? What is the actual point he want to emphasize?

Comment: maybe Uncle Bob is adopting RESTful thinking in extolling the virtues of resource-as-objects.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The three points are separate:

- Class names should be nouns or [noun phrases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase). This means that the name of the class should be something that would be the subject of a verb. In the case of object-oriented design, methods would be the verbs that take place on the thing that the class is a representation of.
- Some words should be avoided. `Manager` indicates a possible [god class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_class). `Info` and `Data` may indicate a dummy data container. Words like this may indicate poor modeling of the problem space.
- Verbs should never be class names. See the first point - classes model things, methods model actions.

Comment: *Words like this may indicate poor modeling of the problem space.* - Well, one would think, either the problem space is modelled poorly or not, independent of the names choosen. A good name doesn't help a poor design; and a good design is only marginally hurt by a poor name.

Comment: And you could take this a step lower when considering how you actually build your class and how it interacts with the outside world - the class's properties would generally be nouns, while the class's methods would generally be verbs

Comment: If your project has a class that you would consider calling "Manager" or "Info" or "Data" then it likely has a dozen such classes, which means you wouldn't use these names. You would have a ThisManager and ThatManager and AnotherManger and so on.

Comment: He says verbs should never be in class names, but I was just rereading Adding Meaningful Context, and in his example on page 29, he names a class GuessStatisticMessage. Now I am confused on the rule, because I interpret his usage of Guess as a verb, as opposed to a noun. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/guess?s=t

Comment: @DevinGleasonLambert But it's not Guess. It's a Guess Statistic Message. A message is a noun. Guess Statistic just describes the type of message that it is - one that messages about guess statistics.

Answer (score 10):

He's trying to draw a distinction between *things* (nouns) and *actions* (verbs). In conventional objected-oriented design, we think of classes as things, and their methods as the actions those things can perform. To *manage* is to take care of or coordinate, while *manager* is a person or thing that manages.

Introductory books usually boil this down to the simplest and most obvious terms possible like a class named *Dog*, with methods *Bark* and *Bite*. In real world classes, the distinction is often a little more subtle, but it's still there. I believe the point Uncle Bob is making, however, is that while *manager* is a noun, but it puts a lot of attention on the what the manager does, and not what it is-it's too vague of a word for describing exactly what is being managed or how.

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of thinking can lead to wrong designs. One of the prime examples is the classic introductory example of a bank account. In almost all OO textbooks, `Account` is an object, `balance` is a field and `transfer` is method. But the correct design would be: `Transfer` is an object, `account` is a field and `balance` is a method. That's how banking systems are *actually* implemented and how banking actually worked before computers.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: that cautionary tale is well worth posting as an answer; that these are general guidelines, and can in certain rare cases lead to bad decomposition.